# IllegalStateException was happen when try to set Encoder for Media Recorder

Tags: android, video, camera, android-camera, recording

Currently I'm working with [`Custom Camera for Recording video`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video).

I already `completed Take Picture from Camera feature` correctly.

I'm trying `making Recording Video from Camera feature work` also.

Actually, If I don't try to set `Encoder` for video, it worked.

But I want customize Recording Video feature, so I already set `Encoder` for `Media Recorder` and always get `IllegalStateException`.

So the thing I want is : `Can set encoder, both audio encoder and video encoder for video` completely without happened exception.

People who know how,

Please tell me,

Really thank you,

Below is the codes.

```
private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(int mode){
        // Should release before use new Preview for Recording Video mode
        CustomCamera.releaseCamera();

        // Initialize camera
        CustomCamera.mCamera = CustomCamera.getCameraInstance(mode);

        // Set orientation display
        CustomCamera.setCameraDisplayOrientation(getActivity(), mode);

        // Should release before use new Preview for Recording Video mode
        CustomCamera.releaseMediaRecorder();

        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        CustomCamera.mCamera.unlock();
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setCamera(CustomCamera.mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // THESE LINES GET CRASH
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);

        // todo Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

        // Step 4: Set output file
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MediaType.VIDEO).toString());

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mCameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());


        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        try {
            CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.prepare();

            CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            CustomCamera.releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            CustomCamera.releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

p/s :

Although I set these lines

```
CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);
```

before or after method `setProfile` (or `setOutputFile`) still get this Exception.

Here is `thrown exception` :

```
    > I/MediaRecorderJNI﹕ prepare: surface=0x1cf9610 (identity=373)
    E/MediaRecorder﹕ audio encoder has already been set
 java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(Native Method)
    at ui.fragment.custom.camera.CameraPreviewFragment.prepareVideoRecorder(CameraPreviewFragment.java:469)
    at ui.fragment.custom.camera.CameraPreviewFragment.onClick(CameraPreviewFragment.java:203)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**SOLUTION**

Set below codes after `setProfile()` method

```
 CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);
```

And remove the line `.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);` in `try-catch` exception. It work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);` line from try catch because there you try to set the AudioEncoder again thus the exception.

**EDIT**
And set `Encoder` after `setProfile()` method, it is correct.

Comment: Oh I forgot. Thank you.